# The project has an assembly reference missing it's <Private> element

Tags: c#, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to use cruise control .net to build a solution using msbuild.  When the project is built inside of Visual Studio (2010) I do not receive any errors; however, when I try to let cruise control build the project I receive the following error:

The project has an assembly reference missing it's <Private> element.

The project does not have any missing assembly references, so I know this is not the issue.

I have scoured Google for an answer and have found nothing... have any of you run into this issue before?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psychic Guess:
Try editing the project file directly and add the following tag

```
<Private>True</Private>
```

to the inside of the Reference tag (for the dependency/ies that is/are having issues)

Otherwise can you link the msbuild output and the project file in question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Another developer has put a check in a Nant build file for a certain set of dlls to have the private element set to True.  Your answer helped me find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a several guesses:

- Are you fetching everything from source control?
- Are any references to dlls using the full path that doesn't exist on the build machine?
- Do you have a difference in build order for debug and release builds?

Comment: 1) yes, cruise control is fetching everything from source control

Comment: 2) I am using relative paths that should work because they work for other projects.

Comment: 3) There is no difference in the build order.